# Proving loose lower and upper bounds

Tags: asymptotics, factorial, upper-lower-bounds

I need to prove

$(n+1)!=\omega (2^n)$

and

$(n-1)!=o(n^n)$

From what I understand, the small omega and o signify, that these are loose upper and lower bounds. If I'm not wrong, this should mean $(n+1)!\geq c(2^n)\forall c>0, n>n_0, \exists n_0>0$ and $(n-1)!\leq cn^n\forall c>0, n>n_0, \exists n_0>0$

However, I do not know how to approach a proof for all values of c. What happens if c approaches infinity or 0? How do I go about finding a value of $n_0$?

Comment: You can use limit variant of definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is written in comment, limit variant of definition for little-$o$ gives
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{n^n}=0$$
same way with little-$\omega$ gives
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{2^n}=\infty$$
From here you can found also values for $n_0$.
For example, can be used inequalities:

$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \lt n! \lt e \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer and the comment, I used Stirling's approximation to prove the first and used a simple expansion to show the second. Please let me know if these approaches are appropriate.

Comment: Yes, but, I think, it's little overhead here. For convenience I added inequalities, which should be helpful.